# Name and list of words with common sounds that share common meanings

Tags: etymology, homophones

There are some words that have similar sounds, though they seem to not share any particular root, and have general connotation. For example, gl-, in gleam, glitter, glisten, has something to do with shiny things. That's the only one I can think of, but I saw an article with one or two other similar "root"s.

Is there a name for words/sounds/roots like these?

Is there a good resource for a list of them? Could be fun to learn them all and use them for poetic effect.

Comment: Your example reminds me of the Jabberwocky and how the nonsense sounds of the words reveal their implied definition: "'twas brillig" which sort of evokes "bright" and "brilliant".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what to call *gl-* in contemporary English (it's not even a [morpheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme)), but in all of your three words, it descends from the same Proto-Indo-European base with the meaning ["to shine, glitter, glow, be warm"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=glisten&searchmode=none).

Two good resources for browsing Proto-Indo-European roots and identifying English words with common origins are:

1. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aList_of_Proto-Indo-European_roots)
2. [The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots](http://books.google.com/books?id=4IHbQgz1nZYC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=ghel-+indo-european&source=bl&ots=1OUBrY4qXR&sig=54ULoC_0-IzTD4SqdBUywanQU5w&hl=en&ei=4Pw_TKOcJZGWsgPknvntDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: is it the same root as "glance, glamor, glare, glean, gloss, glimmer," and "glabrescent"? (Ok forget the last one =P).